# JAX-WS client causes Jetty EofException

Tags: sockets, jetty, jax-ws, webservices-client

I am using an embedded Jetty server to provide Web Services (using Jetty-JAXWS2-SPI to allow Jetty to serve the requests) and I am seeing the following errors when a connection terminates from my JAX-WS test client (generated by `wsimport`):

```
11:32:54.544 [pool-1-thread-5] DEBUG com.mycompany.SomeClass - EOF
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:321) ~[jetty-http-7.3.1.v20110307.jar:7.3.1.v20110307]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:214) ~[jetty-http-7.3.1.v20110307.jar:7.3.1.v20110307]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411) ~[jetty-server-7.3.1.v20110307.jar:7.3.1.v20110307]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:526) ~[jetty-io-7.3.1.v20110307.jar:7.3.1.v20110307]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:41) [jetty-io-7.3.1.v20110307.jar:7.3.1.v20110307]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_24]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_24]
```

Even though these are not important errors (logged at DEBUG level) and I only see them from  my test client, not from soapUI or the 'real' (.NET client), I would rather not see them at all.

I guess the problem is caused by the socket behavior within the JAX-WS client?  Is there any way to influence the socket behavior to avoid this issue?

Other information:

- Others have reported this issue on the Jetty mailing list, also when providing Web Services using Jetty-JAXWS2-SPI.
- I am using JDK 1.6.0_24 and the JAX-WS implementation it contains.
- I am using Jetty 7.3.1-20110307

Comment: hi. do you were able to resolve this issue? im experiencing the same error with paxweb and jetty.

Comment: No - I have implemented my own Jetty Logger class which only allows debug logs from Jetty if a command line/config file option is true (default false).  In other words, I ignore it.